# creating a spring data connection class using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and I am currently using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` 
to `getBean` inside the controller class. This is a small example application
I am building. But what I am trying to do is to move this 
`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`
to a new class and keep it static across application. So I can just call
the newclass to invoke the DAO inside constructor.
I tried a few things but I am getting `NestedServletException` error all the time.

Please suggest me a way to write my new class for data connection which will 
remain in the same state across my application, i.e. I can just call inside each 
controller class and not create a DAO object in constructor each time.

Appreciate any help, suggestion.

thanks
Walker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I assume from the exception name, you are talking about a web application. In that case there is no need for you to create the application context. Spring has its built-in mechanisms. For example, use a listener (in `web.xml`)

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

And so all your beans are getting automatically wired by spring (if, of course, configured properly).

You can still get ahold of the context either via implementing `ApplicationContextAware` or by callign `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext()`, but you shouldn't need this in the general scenario.

You should not use the application context manually. Instead, spring wires your application using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and all your objects (controllers, daos, etc) have their dependencies in place, without the need to "reach" for them in some context.

Comment: Thanks Bozho for the quick reply. I think this will solve my problem. I will give it a shot. Thanks :)